# Computing the median of a data file C++

Tags: c++, class, file-io, binaryfiles

**Hey guys, so I've been reading this exercise for some time now, and it's really confusing.
Can someone please explain to me what i need to do to solve this exercise? I don't really need any code or solutions. Just some steps; explanations or hints would be great. Thanks!**

1. Compute the median of a data file. The median is the middle number in a data set. It is the number that has the same number of data elements greater than the number as there are less than the number. Assume that the data is sorted, in increasing order. The median is the middle element of a file if there are an odd number of elements, or the average of the two middle elements if the file has an even number of elements. To do this, you need to read the file, count the number of elements, close the file, and then once again open the file and find the number you need (the middle).
2. For a sorted file, a quartile is one of three numbers: the first has one-forth the data values less than or equal to it, one-fourth the data values between the first and second numbers, one-fourth the data points between the second and third, and one-fourth above the third quartile. Find the three quartiles for the data file you used for (a).

hint: you should recognize that having done part (a) you have one-third of your job done. (You have the second quartile already.) You also should recognize that you have done almost all the work toward finding the other two quartiles.

Comment: It's simpler to answer such a broad question if you paste up the code you've written so far.

Comment: feeling like an assignment.

Comment: well, the exercise speaks by itself - you should open the file for reading, sort the numbers you've read, find the median using the description in section a... and so on... what is blocking you?

Comment: @NirMH what's blocking me is part b. not understandable.

Comment: You can follow the same method you mentioned at above.

Comment: @vaibhav It is an assignment but i never asked for solutions. i want t do it; just face some problems understanding the concept well.

Comment: lets say you have 10 numbers [1...12] - the first quartile is a number than 1/4 of the numbers are below or match it... which is... 3! - second is 6, third is 9 - think about the year's month - every 3 months you have passed a quarter of the year. you can read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile

Comment: use [boost Accumulator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.median) library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a discussion in the comments - this looks like the submitter problem... so here is my answer:

lets say you have 10 numbers in your file `[1...12]`

The first quartile is a number than 1/4 of the numbers are below or match it... which is... `3`. The second is `6`, the third is `9`.

To simplify your thinking... think about the year's months - every 3 months you have passed a quarter of the year.

For additional infromation you can read at [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile)

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 should not be confusing, right? It is a step-by-step description of what you need to do.

Part 2 is a bit more complicated but you have this hint: **"You also should recognize that you have done almost all the work toward finding the other two quartiles."** I believe it means the following: *after you have done part 1 (therefore found your second quartile), the other two quartiles are nothing but the medians of the two half of the dataset you get after part 1.*

So part 2 is just a reiteration of part 1 on the two half of the dataset (as hinted: "you have one-third of your job done").